# Twitter Web Intent - How to share tweet with dynamic image?

Tags: next.js, twitter

I am working on an online idle game where players can claim missions get a result.
I want to create a web intent that would share dynamically generated images with some text.

Generated images will be stored in a db and publicly available via a URL. I understand I need to use a Twitter Card with a static page hosted in an endpoint.

Afaik, the page should look like this. The Card Validator goes through, and all checks are good:

```js
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Image from 'next/image';

interface SharePageProps {
  imageUrl: string;
}

const SharePage: React.FC<SharePageProps> = ({ imageUrl }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
        <meta name="twitter:site" content="@<user-handle>" />
        <meta name="twitter:title" content="Claim Result" />
        <meta name="twitter:description" content="Claim Result" />
        <meta name="twitter:image" content={imageUrl} />
      </Head>
      <Image
        src={imageUrl}
        alt={'Claim result'}
        layout='fill'
        objectFit='contain'
      />
    </>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { imageUrl } = context.query;

  if (!imageUrl || Array.isArray(imageUrl)) {
    return { props: { imageUrl: '' } };
  }

  const decodedImageUrl = decodeURIComponent(imageUrl);

  return { props: { imageUrl: decodedImageUrl } };
};

export default SharePage;
```

The page returns images with Twitter meta tags. However, the tweet preview does not include the image.
[image]

I am not sure if what I want to do is possible. if so, what I am doing wrong? Any other suggestions to achieve what I want?